# Google map APIs with Observable in Angular2

Tags: google-maps, angular, observable

Newbie in Angular and web programming. However using whatever I have learnt I created an Angular2 component using Google Map APIs and it is routing between two points, however I want to use Observable instead of plain function which gets fired upon response from API. Any help will be highly appreciated. Here is my code:

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnChanges } from '@angular/core';

declare var google: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'gmap',
  templateUrl: 'gmap.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['gmap.component.css']
})
export class GMapComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {

  directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService(); 
  directionsDisplay;  
  map;

  ngOnInit()  {
    this.directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
    this.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('gmap'), {
      zoom: 8,
      center: { lat: 51.59, lng: -0.44 }
    });
    this.directionsDisplay.setMap(this.map);

  }

  onSearchBarGO($event)  {
    var directionsDisplay = this.directionsDisplay;
    //console.log($event);

    this.directionsService.route({
      origin: $event.from,
      destination: $event.to,
      waypoints: [],
      optimizeWaypoints: true,
      travelMode: $event.mode.toUpperCase()
    }, function (response, status) {
      var parent = this;
      if (status === 'OK') {
        directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
      } else {
        window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
      }
    });



  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use Observable's conversion factory methods.

```
Observable.bindCallback(this.directionsService.route)({
  origin: $event.from,
  destination: $event.to,
  waypoints: [],
  optimizeWaypoints: true,
  travelMode: $event.mode.toUpperCase()
})
.subscribe( function (response, status) {
  var parent = this;
  if (status === 'OK') {
    directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
  } else {
    window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
  }
});
```